# Java - Very confused about this recursive binary tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I'll mention that this is for homework. I'm incredibly confused about what I need to do to get this add() function to work. The confusing part is that we are required to define left and right child as type `BinaryTree`, and have the add() function take a `String` rather than a `Node`, which I see in every example on this site. I can't figure out how to set a string to a new child, which is type BinaryTree.

Any help & guidance is appreciated.

```
    import java.util.*;

public class BinaryTree {
  private String  data;
  private BinaryTree leftChild;
  private BinaryTree rightChild;


  public BinaryTree() {
    data = null;
    leftChild = null;
    rightChild = null;
  }


  public BinaryTree(String d) {
    data = d;
    leftChild = null;
    rightChild = null;
  }

  public BinaryTree(String d, BinaryTree left, BinaryTree right) {
    data = d;
    leftChild = left;
    rightChild = right;
  }


  public String getData() { return data; }
  public BinaryTree getLeftChild() { return leftChild; }
  public BinaryTree getRightChild() { return rightChild; }


  public void setData(String d) { data = d; }
  public void setLeftChild(BinaryTree left) { leftChild = left; }
  public void setRightChild(BinaryTree right) { rightChild = right; }


  public String root;

   //This function is what I'm stuggling with
  public void add(String item){



    if(root==null)
    {
        root = item;
    }
    else
    {
        String tmp = root; // save the current root
        if(root.compareTo(item)>0)
        {
            setData(item);
            add(item);  //I should have setBinaryTree(item) here, but I can't convert type String to BinaryTree?.
        }
        else if(root.compareTo(item)<0)
        {
            setData(item);
            add(item);
        }
        root = tmp; // put the root back to its original value
    }
    return;
     } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to recurse while traversing the tree. You are currently trying to add at the same node. Do something like this.

```
if(root.compareTo(item)>0)
{
    if (leftChild == null) {
        leftChild = new BinaryTree(item);
    } else {
        leftChild.add(item);
    } 
}
```

And do something similar for the right child.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a new BinaryTree object by using the constructors provided and assigning it to either the left or right child.

```
public void add(String item){



    if(root==null){
        root = item;
    }else{
        String tmp = root; // save the current root
        BinaryTree bTree = new BinaryTree()
        if(root.compareTo(item)>0){
            bTree.setData(item);
            setLeftChild(bTree);  
        }else if(root.compareTo(item)<0){
            bTree.setData(item);
            setRightChild(bTree);
        }
        root = tmp; // put the root back to its original value
    }
    return;
 }
```